# How to collect useful JavaScript exceptions when using a minifier?

Tags: javascript, exception, minify

I'm a big fan of [Exception Driven Development](http://blog.codinghorror.com/exception-driven-development/). Because the big amount of client-side JavaScript in modern day applications, this means we also collect JavaScript exceptions by sending them to the server.

But as far as I can think of this excludes the use of a minifier? It destroys all the useful information by showing errors like:

`k is undefined, line 2 column 23489 in function l()`

Are there any workarounds for that?

**More info**
Maybe one option would be to create a metadata file at the moment you're minimizing. When this meta data lives on the server, it can remap the minimized error to the original variables and linenumbers with the metadata. Sounds like a lot of work though.

Comment: I'm actually not with you... Can you explain why a minifier destroys all useful information?

Comment: Because you'll get stuff like `k` is undefined, line 2 column 23489 in `function l()`

Comment: Now it's clear, good question...

Comment: If you combine a mapping of long variable/function names to their shortened versions with a simple text-compare as you would with diff or markdown to get your white-space/line-numbers back, I think that could be possible? I'm unaware of any solutions already existing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Javascript source maps after minification to check where the error actually is (and this supports your idea of metafiles).

Hope this article will help you and I understood you right.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/